# Get status CompletedWithWarnings when insert InsightExternalData

Tags: salesforce

My csv file have 3941495 record, I have checked my file, it has exactly 3941495 record after was compressed, but the result on server is 3941489 record. I got status "CompletedWithWarnings", and this is status message

> The job was completed successfully, but failed in the part of the line. From data monitoring to download the error log, please check the failed line.

Does anyone know how to fix it? Or how to download the error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Salesforce Analytics you can monitor an External Data Upload on UI. According [documentation](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/10/en-us/sfdc/pdf/analytics.pdf) (see page 114):

> When you upload an external data file, Wave Analytics kicks off a job
>   that uploads the data into the specified dataset. You can use the data
>   monitor to monitor and troubleshoot the upload job. The Jobs view 
>   of the data monitor shows the status, start time, and duration of each
>   dataflow job and external data upload job. It shows jobs for the last
>   7 days and keeps the logs for 30 days.
>
> In Wave Analytics, click the gear button and then click Data Monitor
>   to open the data monitor. The Jobs view appears by default. The Jobs
>   view displays dataflow and upload jobs. The Jobs view displays each
>   upload job name as . You can hover a job to
>   view the entire name.
>
> To see the latest status of a job, click the Refresh Jobs button.
>
> To view the run-time details for a job, expand the job node. The
>   run-time details display under the job. In the run-time details
>   section, scroll to the right to view information about the rows that
>   were processed.
>
> **To troubleshoot a job that has failed rows, view the error message.**
>   **Also, click the download button in the run-time details section to
>   download the error log.**
>
> Note: Only the user who uploaded the external data file can see the
>   download button. The error log contains a list of failed rows.

Comment: I found that before i see your comment but thank you for helping.